# Silent fail for spring:message

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using Spring Message Source for internationalization of my webapp.

The problem is that a **JspException** is thrown whenever a message is not defined, it's a real pain in developement stage when many texts are added.

What i would like is to log the error (in order to know which texts are missing) and print the key or a placeholder in the generated HTML.

Is this a configurable thing ?

--

edit: there is the **text** attribute, but it needs to be added to each message tag, and it doesn't log anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
one have to set **useCodeAsDefaultMessage** to **true**
it doesn't log errors but at least don't bother you with fatal errors

for example in XML config:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/main</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i18n/dashboard</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

protip: In dev you can also use a **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** with **cacheSeconds=0** to reload translations on each page refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use text attribute in the tag.

```
<spring:message code="welcome.springmvc" text="default text" />
```

Comment: thanks, please see my edit, this is not readable at all when having big amounts of labels